# Measure the percentage of usage of a code formatter

Tags: coding-style, code-formatting

When we are coding it is really important to maintain our code base while preserving coding standards. There are plenty of code formatting tools which are matched with the respective IDE. By using them we can format our code while preserving line indentation. So is there any tool to measure that usage of a code formatting in our code base. I already heard there are some tools to measure the test coverage. There that tool gives a percentage of test cases for actual methods in the code. By using that tool we can find the places where we do not implement test cases. Like that I want to catch the places where I do not use the code formatting. When code base has so many source files and number of lines, it's a tedious task to test if we were forgotten to run the code formatting tool. As I know there's no way to run the tool in all the files at once. So guys, if you know a solution to my problem please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you just run the code formatter over the entire source?

Comment: I have done like that. But when there are so many files in the code base we can forget to run. So it is a tedious task to go through and run again. That's why I am finding such a tool

Comment: Just run them all.  If they produce the same file content after formatting, don't check them in, otherwise do.  Or, attach a formatting action to your checkin script; then they will all change over time.

Comment: What do u mean by 'Just run them all'. Is there a way to run the code formatting tool at once within all the files. I am using brackets text editor and use Ctrl+Alt+B to format the code. There I can format the code in file by file. I am bit new to this field. That's why I am asking again and again.

Comment: You can get beautifier tools; running them over a large code base is then just a matter of scripting in the worst case.  See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/34387/multilanguage-source-code-reformatter-beautifier-pretty-printer

Comment: I am already using beautifier tools and work perfectly for a file by file. So is there a script to execute the tool which format all the files in the project folder at once?

Comment: Yes.  Make a script that enumerates the files and feeds them to the formatter.  If you can't do that, make a DIR or LS listing, and enumerate the file names yourself to make the script.   This should be obvious.  If it isn't you need more practice writing scripts.  Trust me, writing scripts will make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you. I think instead of finding a tool to measure the formatting coverage, it's better idea to write a script to format the all essential files at once. So you are right.